# Weird characters in title if it contain “ ”

Tags: database, title, feed

If my post title contain `“ ”` all the title stored in the database title column in weird characters like this

`"&#1575;&#1604;&#1571;&#1608;&#1585;&#1608;&#1605;&#1578;&#1608;&#1587;&#1591;&#1609; &#1604;&#1604;&#1588;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;" &#1578;&#1576;&#1583;&#1571; &#1578;&#1604;&#1602;&#1609; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1605;&#1575;&#1585;&#1575;&#1578; &#1571;&#1606;&#1588;&#1591;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1580;&#1605;&#1593;&#1610;&#1575;&#1578; &#1575;&#1604;&#1571;&#1607;&#1604;&#1610;&#1577;`

I searched more & more but all i found is some advices to change the table encoding to `UTF8` it is already `UTF8`

After some tests i found that the problem is came from `feedwordpress` plugin not from WordPress itself

How to solve this?

Comment: that doesn't sound like a problem at all. is there any practical problem?

Comment: No, it is a problem at least for me because if i replaced all this weird characters with normal characters my big database's size will decreased from 2G.B to 1.8G.B

Comment: not intending to be sarcastic, but if you have a script to fix it then you are ok. This just sound like something very specific to your DB&WP configuration and I don't believe many even look what there is in the DB unless something actually stops working, so maybe it even happens more but no one knows and cares. Maybe the right thing to do is to try to report it as a bug.

Comment: Ok, i will try to search again & waiting someone save my life. thanks

Comment: What are your exact database settings (table collation, etc) and database-related constant in `wp-config.php`?

Comment: `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');` `define('DB_COLLATE', '');`
`define('WPLANG', '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is:

every normal character stored in weird starts with `&#` ends with `;` like this `&#1642;`

So you can simply 
1-open you dreamweaver

2- new HTML file

3- code tab

4- delete all the code in it

5- put one weird code like this `&#1642;`

6- design tab

7- you can see the original character here

8- execute this sql query in `PHPMyAdmin`:

`update en_posts set post_title = replace(post_title, 'one weird chracter code', 'original character');`

9- repeat this method for every character

10- save your sql queries in txt file

11- execute all this queries every few days

The benefits of this cleaning method:

1- for big wordpress installation this will decrease your database size & speed up your site performance

2- if you using `getposts` or `wp query posts` to execute posts by `s=keyword` all the weird posts will not shows in your query

this is very fine at least for me